# python size of string overestimated by 37 bytes in socket connection

Tags: python, sockets, stream

I'm trying to send a *numpy.array* over a socket connection to a server. I found a behavior I can't seem to get my head around: I use *pickle.dumps* to get a string representation of my array object and use *sys.getsizeof* to estimate the amount of bytes that need to be transfered. However, my code seems to overestimate the length of the data-string by 37 bytes, no matter the size of the input.

Server-code:

```
def recvall(sock, count):
    buf = b''
    while count:
        newbuf = sock.recv(count)
        if not newbuf: return None
        buf += newbuf
        count -= len(newbuf)

        print 'left to read: %i' %count

    return buf


if __name__ == '__main__':
    serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    serversocket.bind((socket.gethostname(), 8089))  #visible to the outside world?
    serversocket.listen(5) # become a server socket, maximum 5 connections


    while True:
        connection, address = serversocket.accept()

        #read message size
        buf = recvall(connection, 4)
        bytes_to_read, = struct.unpack('!I', buf)

        print 'Message size: %i' % bytes_to_read

        #read message
        buf = recvall(connection, bytes_to_read - 37) #HACK: no idea why is that: size is overestimated by 37?!
        connection.close()

        reconstructed = pickle.loads(buf);

        img.imsave('out.png', reconstructed);
        print reconstructed.shape
```

client-code:

```
#read image
im = img.imread(sys.argv[1])
im_str = pickle.dumps(im)


#### communication
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('ororea', 8089))

tmp = struct.pack('!I', int(sys.getsizeof(im_str))); #unsigned int

#print sys.getsizeof(tmp)

clientsocket.sendall(tmp)
clientsocket.sendall(im_str);

clientsocket.close()
```

Like this, the transfer works, but I don't understand why 37 bytes less are sent.

best regards,
Dominic

Comment: What do the input, packets, and output look like?

Comment: You should use `len`, not `sys.getsizeof`.

Comment: @falsetru: thank you, that solves the problem. I found this in a tutorial for socket connections. Just looked it up in the API and also found the explanation: `getsizeof()` calls the object’s `__sizeof__` method and adds an additional garbage collector overhead if the object is managed by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comment of @falsetru has the solution:

> You should use `len`, not `sys.getsizeof`.